# Как сделать проверку есть ли сверху блок с тегом в unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть player, который бежит по платформе, так вот мне нужно проверить если сверху находится платформа с тегом CantGo, то он не сможет туда двигаться. Как мне оформить такую проверку.

Comment: кто такой верх то?

Comment: Эээ... Добавьте и игроку, и платформе boxcollider и rigidbody, и ваш игрок не сможет пройти сквозь платформу